# Where is that backup file?

Tags: sql-server

I want to restore a database using the most recent backup. In SSMS, it says there was a backup done this morning at 1:00 AM. Screenshot:

[image]

If I select this backup, it fails, saying the file {0DDBD48C-42AB-4DBD-ACD5-56DEAF5D1D1C}6 does not exist.

Generating a script from the SSMS window results in this:

```
USE [master]
RESTORE DATABASE [aleyantW2P] FROM  DISK = N'{0DDBD48C-42AB-4DBD-ACD5-56DEAF5D1D1C}6' WITH  FILE = 1,  NORECOVERY,  NOUNLOAD,  REPLACE,  STATS = 5

GO
```

I do believe the backup really happened -- there is evidence in the SQL log -- but somehow the name is bogus. How do I find where the BAK file really is?

**Additional Info**:

- I am running Windows 2012 R2 Standard, and Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Web Edition ( 11.0.2218.0 (X64) )
- I am not running Sharepoint or System Center, so I don't think this is a DPM backup.
- I do really think there was a backup done and that it completed successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at one of my own SQL Servers that's running regular Windows Server Backups as well as SQL Server level backups. I'm reasonably certain that this is a VSS backup. As such, you probably won't be able to restore from it. (It's not supported, because the amount of time it takes to run can cause mdf/ldf mismatch.) You'll need to find a different backup set.

Comment: Nope. This generated the same script as SSMS did: `RESTORE DATABASE [aleyantW2P] FROM DISK = '{0DDBD48C-42AB-4DBD-ACD5-56DEAF5D1D1C}6' with file = 1, NORECOVERY, REPLACE`

Comment: I looked at one of my own SQL Servers that's running regular Windows Server Backups as well as SQL Server level backups.  I'm reasonably certain that this is a VSS backup.  As such, you probably won't be able to restore from it.  (It's not supported, because the amount of time it takes to run can cause mdf/ldf mismatch.)  You'll need to find a different backup set.

Comment: OK. I think you're right -- looking again at the SQL log, I see the backup bracketed by messages saying VSS is starting and stopping. Can you reenter that comment as an answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: Done!  (I replaced my script with the comment, and have to type more for the comment to be accepted.)

Answer (score 0):

Was the backup taken by a 3rd party tool or backup appliance?  That's my guess.  You'll have to use the 3rd party tool to restore the backup in most cases.

If not, ask whoever schedules and runs the backups.  Are they in a maintenance plan or a SQL Server Agent job?